# Performance issue with Zend Framework

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework

I added Zend Framework to my php project 1 month ago. I am using Zend_Measure and Zend_Locale for formatting the numbers to the good locale.

I am using php 5.3 with APC and Zend Framework 1.11.

I have a major issue with the export of raw data from my database. Excluding the mysql query time which is negligible the php export with formatting of the records takes 3.5 seconds per 1000 records. All this time is spend in `Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber()`. How can I improve the performance of this?

This benchmark has been done on my own computer (Macbook pro i5). 
On our production server it take 70 seconds per 1000 records!!! This server is a 2GB rackspaceCloud Cloud server with centos and only our web application running.

There is a 20 factor between the macbook and the rackspace server performance. Is my macbook so powerful? I don't think so...

---

UPDATE

After doing some profiling it appear that the bottleneck is `Zend_Cache_Backend_File->_fileGetContents`. It use by default Zend_Cache_Backend_File. How can I configure Zend Framework to use `Zend_Cache_Backend_Apc` or `Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels`? It could maybe improve the performance...

Comment: See my updated answer to configure which cache to use. Looks like your speed issues are caused by slow disk write/read speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you setup the global cache for `Zend_Locale`? Check this [doc page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.introduction.html) and scroll to the bottom.

Also, check your APC settings. I don't use APC myself but have had performance issues with XCache when the cache size was too small. This could also be an issue for your configuration.

---

To configure the cache used by `Zend_Locale` and `Zend_Local_Format` use `Zend_Locale::setCache($cache)` and `Zend_Locale_Format::setOptions(array('cache' => $adapter))`. As can be found in the manual.

Comment: I have Zend Framework 1.11 and since 1.08 the cache is activated by default. "When no cache is set, then Zend_Locale will automatically set a cache itself." When I look at my apc.php page, the graphs show a lot of free space...

Comment: I believe that should be 1.8? Anyway, APC is working correctly, i.e. it's activated? Without any code to show it's a bit hard to figure out what's going on. Can you reduce the code to only the `Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber()` bit and benchmark its performance?

Comment: I am now setting the cache with `Zend_Locale::setCache($cache);` with `$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Apc');` and it improve a lot the performance of my export. The default "file" cache backend was really slow on my rackspace VPS... Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: It seems like disk i/o is slow on that VPS. Never experienced such issues with Rackspace Cloud Servers but perhaps you got your instance running on a tad bit older machine?